# pyspark hive_table dataframe manipulation error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pyspark

I'm new to spark and I'm trying to experiment with MinMaxScaler. 
I'm Working with Spark 2.1.1 in and writing in Jupyter 
So my steps are.
1.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors 
batch1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT field1 FROM hive_table limit 10000")
```

As stated in documentation in order to use `MinMaxScaler` my field should be `Vectors.dense`. So here is what I do next.

```
batch2 = batch1.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense(row.field1))
```

After this step I cannot do anything on batch2. For example if I do

```
for record in batch2.collect():
    print(record)
```

I get this kind of error

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 30 in stage 25.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 30.0 in stage 25.0 (TID 389, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** 
Here is the output for `batch1.printSchema()`

```
root
 |-- field1: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: could you add result of batch1.printSchema()  or batch1.show(1) ?

Comment: @chlebek sorry for late reply, Please see Update in question. added print schema result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your column `row.field1` is not an array, **[edit]** however Vectors.dense works with single values as input so I guess that your column `field1` contains some non numeric records, you can check it using  `batch2.select(f.col('field1').cast("int")).filter(f.col('field1').isNull()).count()`

see example below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(123, 25), (23, 22), (2, 20)], ['c1', 'c2'])
df.show()
df.printSchema()

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.select(f.array('*')).toDF('arr')
df2.show()

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

rdd = df2.rdd.map(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x.arr))

for record in rdd.collect():
    print(record)
```

```
    +---+---+
    | c1| c2|
    +---+---+
    |123| 25|
    | 23| 22|
    |  2| 20|
    +---+---+

    root
     |-- c1: long (nullable = true)
     |-- c2: long (nullable = true)

    +---------+
    |      arr|
    +---------+
    |[123, 25]|
    | [23, 22]|
    |  [2, 20]|
    +---------+

    [123.0,25.0]
    [23.0,22.0]
    [2.0,20.0]
```

and with non numerical value:

```
spark.createDataFrame([("a123", 25), ("23", 22), ("2", 20)], ['c1', 'c2'])\
.rdd.map(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x.c1)).first()
```

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 169.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 169.0 (TID 485, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Did you expect the checking to work on batch2? on batch2 I receive `AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'select' ` and on batch1 the output is 0